# Is there a way to load the wiki-fasttext model faster with load_word2vec_format

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, gensim, fasttext

Loading the wiki-fasttext model with the gensim library takes **six** minutes.

I'm aware of ways to cache the model but I'm looking for ways to speedup the initial model loading. The specific api is below:

```
en_model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(os.path.join(root_dir, model_file))
```

Granted, wiki-fasttext a very large model, however I have load the same model in many languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use `limit=vector_num` argument for load `vector_num` word vectors from a file. You will not load all the vectors, but you can speed up the loading process.

Comment: I am looking to remove wordvectors from the model based on the English Wikipedia that are not included in the dataset that I want to analyse.

I.e. I want to load a subset of vectors from the FastText model. How can I do that ? Iterating over the model and writing into a new one destroys the type.